# send an integer value from my View to the controller in order to load a jQuery datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, wcf, datatable

I have been working on a MVC C# project and need to load a jQuery datatable from a specific db' table, the datatable must show the records of a specific region (and the regions are integers for example 01, 02, 03...) and no more, what I want to know is how the send an integer (that represents a specific region) to the controller from the DataTable script code.

this is the code of my datatable

```
 $('#myTable').DataTable({
            searching: false,
            paging: true,
            responsive: true,
            ordering: false,
            bInfo: false,
            bLengthChange: false,
            processing: true,
            info: false,
            deferRender: true,
            orderMulti: false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../home/CargarTabla",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [ ... all my columns
```

and this is the code of my MVC controller, it calls a WCF Service to get the info and just for debug I've specified a int value(example=28) and send the value in (info = cliente.CargarDatatable(ejemplo)) as I show in the code below

```
public ActionResult CargarTabla()
        {
            int example= 28;
            ProxyGFC.ServiceGFCClient cliente = new ProxyGFC.ServiceGFCClient();
            List<WcfService.Entidades.EmpleadoDatatable> info = new List<WcfService.Entidades.EmpleadoDatatable>();
            info = cliente.CargarDatatable(ejemplo);

            // a lot of boring code here...but it works
            return Json(new { data = lista }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

How do I send the integer value from my View to the controller ?

Comment: `./home/CargarTabla?id=100` as the ajax url and add a parameter called `id` of `int` type to your method and use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a parameter in your Controller Action and pass that parameter into your method that populates your value:

```
// The id value will read any querystring values or those found in the request
// as set them to the expected value
public ActionResult CargarTabla(int id)
{
      // Use your id here to pass along to your service    
}
```

Then simply adjust your client-side call to pass it along either as a querystring parameter (e.g. `"url": "../home/CargarTabla?id=42"`). You could do this dynamically as well by referencing an HTML element and passing its value along:

```
var id = $('selector').val();
$('#myTable').DataTable({
      // Omitted for brevity
      "ajax": {
            "url": "../home/CargarTabla?id=" + id,
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json",
            // Another option may be to use a data object instead of a querystring param.
            data { id: id }
      }
});
```